# “How do you want to open this file” for run commands

Tags: windows-10-preview

When I run `%temp%` using <kbd>Win+R</kbd>, I get a popup:

> "How do you want to open this file?"

To prevent the popup, I can encapsulate using double quotation marks: `"%temp%"`.

How to fix it?

Comment: Have you checked your environment variables?

Answer (score 0):

Generally, when you open something using `%..` variables, they are converted into the real address, like:

`%tmp%`---> `C:\Users\UserName\AppData\Local\Temp`

So, if you have a space (a rare occasion though) in your username, and try to open `%tmp%` in programs (like `cmd` or etc) instead of:

`C:\Users\your name\AppData\Local\Temp`

it might try to open

`C:\Users\your` (because, generally **space** splits the parameter)

and as there is no file there, it might redirect the execution to "Internet Explorer" (or undefined program) which might show that message.

---

The reason double quote <kbd>"</kbd> solves the problem, is because quoted parameters are taken as one parameter and are not split even if they contain **space** or any division character.